# Add EditText as required and retrieve data from all EditTexts

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I need to create as many Edittexts required when add button is clicked. And needs to retrieve datas in each EditTexts and store in a arrayList.

I have attached images below.

before clicking add button
[image: before clicking add button]

after clicking new button, creates a new edit text
[image: after clicking new button, creates a new edit text]

Comment: @ADM i have searched lots of posts regarding this. Could not find one. Thank you for the share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to create two list variable:

```
List<EditText> list = new ArrayList<EditText>();
List<String> listText = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then, when you click the "new" button you need to add new `EditText` in your layout:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        EditText editText = new EditText(context);
        layout.addView(editText);
        list.add(editText);
    }
});
```

In another button click or whatever trigger you have you need to get text from `EditText` list:

```
for (EditText editText : list) {
    listText.add(editText.getText().toString());
}
```

Comment: thanks for your valuable answer. let me try this.

Comment: Is this what you were trying to do?